# How to return button that is in Control.ControlCollection?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a button that I have added to Controls for example:

```
Controls.Add(MyButton);
```

But now I want to return the button that is in that controls collection. How do I access it from the ControlsCollection. I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
return Controls[0] as Button
```

Comment: Are you talking about [`ControlCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) from [tag:winforms], [`ControlCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.controlcollection?view=netframework-4.8) from System.Web.UI, or maybe something else?  I'm guessing it's [tag:winforms], and if so, please [edit] your question and [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) it as such so you can receive an applicable answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can try use linq `FirstOrDefault` after `Cast` extension method to get the first `Button` type in `Controls` of `Form.ControlCollection`

```
Controls.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(x => x is Button);
```

Comment: Replaced <Control> with <Button> and worked exactly like I needed, thanks!